# Create unary GreaterThan Linq.Expression by combining two expressions

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I have two Expressions (can be constant or property expression) `leftExpr` and `rightExpr`, and would like to create a combined expression that is a greater than between the results, like this:

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(x => Expression.GreaterThan(leftExpr(x),rightExpr(x))
```

This obviously doesnt work, what is the right way to go? (I'm new to expression trees)

**Code of left and rightExpr:**

```
Expression leftExpr, rightExpr;
if (left_element.All(char.IsDigit)) 
{
    leftExpr = Expression.Constant(int.Parse(left_element));
}
else
{
    leftExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Parameter(t), left_element);
}

if (right_element.All(char.IsDigit)) 
{
    rightExpr = Expression.Constant(int.Parse(right_element));
}
else
{
    rightExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Parameter(t), right_element);
}
```

Comment: Why not just do `var result = Expression.GreaterThan(leftExpr, rightExpr)`?

Comment: Why do you use this strange `if(condition);else{...}` syntax? Why not simply negating the condition: `if(!condition){...}` ?

Comment: @Koopakiller He is doing stuff in the `if`. Very strange formatting though, to use `{}` on the `else` but not on the `if`.

Comment: Create helper methods leftExpr() and rightExpr() and put you two 'if' statements into each of these two new methods.

Comment: how can i filter an IEnumerable<t> using the var result = Expression.GreatherThan(leftExpr, rightExpr) expression?

Comment: @HjalmarZ Oh, I has not saw it - but the formatting is not very readable

Comment: you use `Expression.Lambda` wrong it should be like: `Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(Expression.GreaterThan(leftExpr,rightExpr), x)` where `x` is `ParamenterExpression`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use it a bit wrong: first, you should use *one* ParameterExpression, and fix you `Expression.Lambda`. If fix this, it look a like

```
Expression leftExpr, rightExpr;
var x = Expression.Parameter(t);
if (left_element.All(char.IsDigit)) 
{
    leftExpr = Expression.Constant(int.Parse(left_element));
}
else
{
    leftExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(x, left_element);
}

if (right_element.All(char.IsDigit)) 
{
    rightExpr = Expression.Constant(int.Parse(right_element));
}
else
{
    rightExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(x, right_element);
}
```

and

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(Expression.GreaterThan(leftExpr,rightExpr),x);
```